# What can we understand when we increase the $N$-point DFT for a given signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, dsp-core

I have an input sequence $$x(n)=\cos(0.48\pi n)+\cos(0.52\pi n).$$ I am determining its spectrum (amplitude of DFT values) based on the finite number of samples.

For Example :

1. Taking the first $10$ samples of $x(n)$, $n=0, \ldots, 9$, calculating the $10$-point DFT of $x(n)$
2. Using the $10$ samples from part $1$, calculating and plotting the $100$-point DFT.
3. Taking the first $100$ samples of $x(n)$, $n=0, \ldots, 99$, ploting the $100$-point DFT of $x(n)$.

**Questions:**

- Why are we going for a $100$-point DFT/ $200$-oint DFT ?
- And what happens when we take $10$ samples and calculate $100$-point DFT ?

Comment: Increase by zero-padding, increasing the sample rate, or sampling for a longer length of signal?

Comment: Increase the sampling for a longer length of the signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the signal length **$M$** remains the same but only number of points **$N$** in DFT is increased (assuming $M \leq N$) then this will give you the **finely** spaced samples $X[k]$ of the **same** true spectrum $X(e^{j\omega})$ as given by the DFT frequency sampling relation: also known as the **zero-padding** result 
$$X[k] = X(e^{j\frac{2 \pi}{N}k}) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} {x[n]e^{-j\frac{2 \pi}{N}k}} = \sum_{n=0}^{M-1} {x[n]e^{-j\frac{2 \pi}{N}k}} ~~~ , ~~~~  k=0,1,2,...,N-1 $$

On the other hand, if both the analysed signal length $M$ and the DFT length $N$ are increased (assuming $M=N$) by using a longer analysis **window** (considering $x[n]$ defined for a very long, possibly infinite length duration) then the **windowed true spectrum** of the underlying signal whose samples are investigated, is also enhanced, thereby providing samples $X[k]$ of a **higher frequency resolution** spectrum of the very long length signal $x[n]$